# Using Regex.Replace to keep characters that can be vary

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have the following:

```
string text = "version=\"1,0\"";
```

I want to replace the `comma` for a `dot`, while keeping the 1 and 0, BUT keeping in mind that they be different in different situations! It could be `version="2,3"` .

The smart ass and noob-unworking way to do it would be:

```
           for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z <= 9; z++)
                {
                    text = Regex.Replace(text, "version=\"i,z\"", "version=\"i.z\"");
                }
            }
```

But of course.. it's a string, and I dont want `i` and `z` be behave as a string in there.

I could also try the lame but working way:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, "version=\"1,", "version=\"1.");
text = Regex.Replace(text, "version=\"2,", "version=\"2.");
text = Regex.Replace(text, "version=\"3,", "version=\"3.");
```

And so on.. but it would be lame.

Any hints on how to single-handedly handle this?

Edit: I have other commas that I don't wanna replace, so `text.Replace(",",".")` can't do

Comment: You have other commas in the same string you don't want to replace, right?

Comment: right :) otherwise i would just `text.replace` sorry about that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a regex like this to locate the comma

```
Regex reg = new Regex("(version=\"[0-9]),([0-9]\")");
```

Then do the repacement:

```
text = reg.Replace(text, "$1.$2");
```

You can use $1, $2, etc. to refer to the matching groups in order.

Answer (score 3):

```
(?<=version=")(\d+),
```

You can try this.See demo.Replace by `$1.`

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/52

Answer (score 2):

You can perhaps use capture groups to keep the numbers in front and after for replacement afterwards for a more 'traditional way' to do it:

```
string text = "version=\"1,0\"";
var regex = new Regex(@"version=""(\d*),(\d*)""");
var result = regex.Replace(text, "version=\"$1.$2\"");
```

Using parens like the above in a regex is to create a capture group (so the matched part can be accessed later when needed) so that in the above, the digits before and after the comma will be stored in `$1` and `$2` respectively.

---

But I decided to delve a little bit further and let's consider the case if there are more than one comma to replace in the version, i.e. if the text was `version="1,1,0"`. It would actually be tedious to do the above, and you would have to make one replace for each 'type' of version. So here's one solution that is sometimes called a callback in other languages (not a C# dev, but I fiddled around lambda functions and it seems to work :)):

```
private static string SpecialReplace(string text)
{
    var result = text.Replace(',', '.');
    return result;
}
public static void Main()
{
    string text = "version=\"1,0,0\"";
    var regex = new Regex(@"version=""[\d,]*""");
    var result = regex.Replace(text, x => SpecialReplace(x.Value));
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

The above gives `version="1.0.0"`.

`"version=""[\d,]*"""` will first match any sequence of digits and commas within `version="..."`, then pass it to the next line for the replace.

The replace takes the matched text, passes it to the lambda function which takes it to the function `SpecialReplace`, where a simple text replace is carried out only on the matched part.

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/1owx0C)